# How can I navigate to a different href first, then let the code continue, using just JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, href, window.location

When I enter this code into the console on Chrome browser, the alert comes first, followed by the new href, even though the 'window.location.replace()' is in-front of the alert:

```
window.location.replace('http://stackoverflow.com/');
alert('hi');
```

I would like to know how to navigate to the new page, and then let the alert happen. How would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to know how to navigate to the new page, and then let the alert happen. How would i do that?

You can't. The JavaScript environment in browsers is tied to the page. When the page is torn down, the environment is torn down with it. Even if you were to do something like this:

```
// Example of something that DOESN'T work
window.location.replace('http://stackoverflow.com/');
setTimeout(function() {
    alert('hi');
}, 100);
```

...the timer callback would never fire, because the environment is torn down before it has a chance to.

All you can do is pass information to the next page so that code *on that next page* runs.

Answer (score 0):

I think @T.J Crowder's answer covers it up very well, but I just wanted to emphasize his last sentence

> All you can do is pass information to the next page so that code on
>   that next page runs.

That would of course only be implying you are redirecting the user to a location you own (unless you own Stack Overflow and I wasn't aware...), and a solution would be to pass GET parameters for example to alert the message you want, like this

```
window.location.replace('http://stackoverflow.com/?msg=hi');
```

Then in the other page, you would get the parameter `msg` and simply do

```
alert(get_msg);
```

The message can of course be passed via other way than GET (POST for example), and it is how most "known" frameworks work with their "flash" messages (which is no more JavaScript related)